# SP initiated url gives a blank page when added to intranet zone

Tags: adfs

I have RP added to ADFS 3.0 for SSO. This is SP initiated sign-on. Whenver I add the sp initiated url to intranet zone it gives me a blank page from domain joined machines. However, it works good when I remove it from intranet zone and add it to trusted site. It doesn't promt for password and gets me directly in to the site. That is what exactly I want, user should not be prompted for password in intranet. But I am scared if I do not add it to the intranet zone, after a period of time it will start prompting me for password. I want a seamless sso in intranet.

Answer (score 0):

It's the adfs host name that needs to be in intranet to do windows integrated authentication; not the sp URL. This assumes you have configured intranet zone in internet explorer to do automatic sign in.